# How can I remove first element of user control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control, and have taken  as a first element for designing. Now runtime, i want to remove  and want to remove the instance of Grid element and want to add Panel element. How it is possible?

Comment: Although it doesn't answer your question...I recommend, don't use elements only for designing purposes. It's a pretty odd approach. Design your UI with the elements you want to use during run time. How do you want to ensure that you layout is still proper after replacing one element with another?

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing child controls can be trickey, so I would recommend that you have both controls as children to your UserControl and change their `Visibility` as you need to

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty hard to understand. Maybe you should re-read before posting.

As far as i understand it, you want to change the content of a UserControl? Thats simple: Just set the Content-Property of the UserControl with any other element you like.

A "Panel" is not real element, its a base class for other panels like Grid or Canvas. So if you want to replace a Grid as content of your UserControl with a Canvas, just use:

```cs
userControl.Content = new Canvas();
```

If this does not help you, please rework your question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of following code, we can find first element of UserControl.

```
ContentPresenter _ContentPresenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0), 0) as ContentPresenter;
FrameworkElement _First_Element = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(_ContentPresenter, 0) as FrameworkElement;
```